# Get characters from string with regular expression

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to make a regular expression that match chars(letters a-z or digits 0-9) but only until 4 chars are left. The string will ALWAYS look like this:

1as3-4123-5fa12-4124-41aa-1123

I have tried the next regular expression, but it only returns the first match (1as3 in this case) If I take out the '-' it works fine, but with them, I can't make it work to get the match more than once.

```
/^\w{1,26}/g
```

How can I make to get it more than once?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])+(?=-)
```

It matches groups of letters and numbers that are behind the hyphen (-).  This will exclude the last 4 characters since there is no hyphen in front of it.

Tested at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GWjglD/1)

Comment: Why not just `uuid.substring(0, 25)`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a positive lookahead here:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]*(?=.{4}$)/g
```

### Demo

The pattern `[A-Za-z0-9\-]*` will consume as many characters as possible, excluding only the final four characters.

Comment: Doesn't this match the hypen (-) too, which the OP doesn't want?

Comment: @Shar1er80 It isn't completely clear what the OP wants exactly.  I interpreted the requirement as meaning to match everything except the final 4 characters.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with "he string will ALWAYS look like this" by it always has the same length, you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add a hyphen because that is not matched by `\w` and will match only the first 4 `1as3`.

[`^[\w-]{1,26}`](https://regex101.com/r/3DJmVw/1)

Or use `^[\w-]{26}` if you are always matches 26 characters.

If you only want to match letters a-z or digits 0-9 including the `-` you could use [`^[a-z0-9-]{1,26}`](https://regex101.com/r/3DJmVw/2/) because `\w` also matches an underscore and uppercase characters.

If you want to match only `[a-z0-9]` an not a hyphen until 4 chars `[a-z0-9]` are left, you might use a positive lookahead that will assert that what is on the right side are 4 times `[a-z0-9]` preceded with an optional `-` at the end of the line `$`:

[`[a-z0-9]+(?=[a-z0-9-]*(?:-?[a-z0-9]){4}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/kuuTcx/1)